# Create a custom split method that keeps the delimiters in Swift

Tags: algorithm, swift

I have implemented a custom split method that replicates the original functionality of the collection's split method in Swift and keep the delimiters (element separator). After a lot of trial and error I think I was able to make it behave properly:

```
extension Collection {
    func splitAndKeep(
        maxSplits: Int = .max,
        omittingEmptySubsequences: Bool = true,
        whereSeparator isSeparator: (Element) throws -> Bool
    ) rethrows -> [SubSequence] {
        precondition(maxSplits >= 0, "maxSplits can not be negative")
        guard !isEmpty else { return [] }
        var subsequences: [SubSequence] = []
        var start = startIndex
        while
            let idx = try self[start...].indices
                .first(where: { try isSeparator(self[$0]) }),
            subsequences.count < maxSplits {
            let subsequenceRange = start..<idx
            if !omittingEmptySubsequences {
                subsequences.append(self[subsequenceRange])
            } else if !subsequenceRange.isEmpty {
                subsequences.append(self[subsequenceRange])
            }
            if subsequences.count == maxSplits {
                start = idx
                break
            }
            start = index(after: idx)
            let separatorRange = idx..<start
            if !omittingEmptySubsequences {
                subsequences.append(self[separatorRange])
            } else if !separatorRange.isEmpty {
                subsequences.append(self[separatorRange])
            }
        }
        let tailRange = start..<endIndex
        if !omittingEmptySubsequences {
            subsequences.append(self[tailRange])
        } else if !tailRange.isEmpty {
            subsequences.append(self[tailRange])
        }
        return subsequences
    }
}
```

---

```
let string = "*(22+13)/"
let delimiters = Set<Character>("{+-/*()%}.")

let ss = string.splitAndKeep(whereSeparator: delimiters.contains)  // ["*", "(", "22", "+", "13", ")", "/"]
let ss1 = string.splitAndKeep(maxSplits: 0, whereSeparator: delimiters.contains)  // ["*(22+13)/"]
let ss2 = string.splitAndKeep(maxSplits: 1, whereSeparator: delimiters.contains)  // ["*", "(22+13)/"]
let ss3 = string.splitAndKeep(maxSplits: 2, whereSeparator: delimiters.contains)  // ["*", "(", "22+13)/"]

let ss4 = string.splitAndKeep(omittingEmptySubsequences: false, whereSeparator: delimiters.contains)  // ["", "*", "", "(", "22", "+", "13", ")", "", "/", ""]
let ss5 = string.splitAndKeep(maxSplits: 0, omittingEmptySubsequences: false, whereSeparator: delimiters.contains)  // ["*(22+13)/"]
let ss6 = string.splitAndKeep(maxSplits: 1, omittingEmptySubsequences: false, whereSeparator: delimiters.contains)  // ["", "*(22+13)/"]
let ss7 = string.splitAndKeep(maxSplits: 2, omittingEmptySubsequences: false, whereSeparator: delimiters.contains)  // ["", "*", "(22+13)/"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is written clearly and works correctly, as far as I can see. Here are some suggestions, some of which are a matter of personal preference.

Some of the following suggestions are also inspired by the implementation of [`Collection.split()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2294101-split) which can be inspected in [Collection.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Collection.swift#L1547).

I am not a huge fan of the “double negation” in

```
guard !isEmpty else { return [] }
```

and would write that as

```
if isEmpty {
    return []
}
```

If a `if` or `while` statement is used with a multi-line condition then it can be difficult to recognize where the condition ends and the loop body starts:

```
while
    let idx = try self[start...].indices
        .first(where: { try isSeparator(self[$0]) }),
    subsequences.count < maxSplits {
    let subsequenceRange = start..<idx
    // ...
}
```

One option is to move the left curly brace to the next line:

```
while
    let idx = try self[start...].indices
        .first(where: { try isSeparator(self[$0]) }),
    subsequences.count < maxSplits
{
    let subsequenceRange = start..<idx
    // ...
}
```

A sequence like

```
let subsequenceRange = start..<idx
if !omittingEmptySubsequences {
    subsequences.append(self[subsequenceRange])
} else if !subsequenceRange.isEmpty {
    subsequences.append(self[subsequenceRange])
}
```

occurs three times in your code: For the current slice from the last separator to the newly found separator, for the separator itself, and for the remaining slice at the end.

Moving this logic to a (nested) function removes this duplication, and makes the overall logic easier to recognize.

Combining all these suggestions, the code would look like this:

```
extension Collection {
    func splitAndKeep(
        maxSplits: Int = .max,
        omittingEmptySubsequences: Bool = true,
        whereSeparator isSeparator: (Element) throws -> Bool
    ) rethrows -> [SubSequence] {
        precondition(maxSplits >= 0, "maxSplits can not be negative")
        if isEmpty {
            return []
        }

        var subsequences: [SubSequence] = []
        var start = startIndex
        
        func appendSubsequence(upTo: Index) {
            if !omittingEmptySubsequences || upTo != start {
                subsequences.append(self[start..<upTo])
            }
        }
        
        while
            var idx = try self[start...].indices
                .first(where: { try isSeparator(self[$0]) }),
            subsequences.count < maxSplits
        {
            // Append the slice self[start..<idx]:
            appendSubsequence(upTo: idx)
            start = idx
            if subsequences.count == maxSplits {
                break
            }
            // Append the separator:
            formIndex(after: &idx)
            appendSubsequence(upTo: idx)
            start = idx
        }
        // Append the remaining slice:
        appendSubsequence(upTo: endIndex)

        return subsequences
    }
}
```

Finally you could also provide a method taking a single separator instead of a predicate, like the [corresponding Collection method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/2906704-split):

```
extension Collection where Element: Equatable {
    func splitAndKeep(
        separator: Element,
        maxSplits: Int = .max,
        omittingEmptySubsequences: Bool = true
    ) -> [SubSequence] {
        splitAndKeep(
            maxSplits: maxSplits,
            omittingEmptySubsequences: omittingEmptySubsequences,
            whereSeparator: { $0 == separator }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I definitely agree about the `appendSubsequence` and even thought about adding it before asking this question. Thank you so much @MartinR.

Comment: @LeoDabus: You are welcome!

Comment: We can also move `start = idx` to the end of the `appendSubsequence` method `start = upTo`

Comment: @LeoDabus: Yes, I had thought about that, but then the function has “too much side effect” in my opinion, and makes the main loop less self-explaining. Surely a matter of personal taste.

Comment: I agree. I did think about maybe renaming the method as well.

Comment: Could `var idx = try self[start...].indices.first(where: { try isSeparator(self[$0]) })` be simplified to `var idx = try self[start...].firstIndex(where: isSeparator)`?

Comment: @Rob: Yes, definitely! – Perhaps you want to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

I might suggest a few refinements on Martin’s answer (+1):

- If you’re going to mutate `subsequences` in `appendSubsequence`, you might as well advance the `start` index there, too;
- A matter of personal opinion, but I find expressions like `!range.isEmpty` to be more functionally expressive than `upTo != start`.
- The expression:

  ```swift
  let idx = try self[start...].indices
              .first(where: { try isSeparator(self[$0]) })
  ```

  Can be simplified to:

  ```swift
  var idx = try self[start...].firstIndex(where: isSeparator)
  ```

Thus:

```swift
extension Collection {
    func splitAndKeep(
        maxSplits: Int = .max,
        omittingEmptySubsequences: Bool = true,
        whereSeparator isSeparator: (Element) throws -> Bool
    ) rethrows -> [SubSequence] {
        precondition(maxSplits >= 0, "maxSplits can not be negative")

        if isEmpty {
            return []
        }

        var subsequences: [SubSequence] = []
        var lowerBound = startIndex

        func appendAndAdvance(with upperBound: Index) {
            let range = lowerBound ..< upperBound
            if !omittingEmptySubsequences || !range.isEmpty {
                subsequences.append(self[range])
                lowerBound = upperBound
            }
        }

        while
            var upperBound = try self[lowerBound...].firstIndex(where: isSeparator),
            subsequences.count < maxSplits
        {
            appendAndAdvance(with: upperBound)    // portion before separator
            if subsequences.count == maxSplits {
                break
            }
            formIndex(after: &upperBound)
            appendAndAdvance(with: upperBound)    // separator
        }
        appendAndAdvance(with: endIndex)          // trailing portion

        return subsequences
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Rob for your suggestions as well !!